# Geocoder Runtime error in new flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, google-geocoder

I have been using [Geocoder-0.1.2](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder#-readme-tab-), from starting, and it did not cause me any problem. I have just upgraded my flutter and while running my project, I get this error:

```
Compiler message:
file:///Users/alok/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoder-0.1.2/lib/services/d
istant_google.dart:38:56: Error: The argument type 'Utf8Decoder' can't be assigned to the
parameter type 'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>'.
 - 'Utf8Decoder' is from 'dart:convert'.
 - 'StreamTransformer' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Uint8List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to
'StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>'.
    final responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
                                                       ^
Compiler failed on /Users/alok/MyProjects/newmonkapp/lib/main.dart
Error launching application on iPhone 7.
```

Since the error shows it is in the `main.dart`, there is no code related to that, I have doubled checked it. Here you go.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(NewMonkApp());

class NewMonkApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("in the main builder");

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'XYZ',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 251, 1),
        fontFamily: 'SF Pro',
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(253, 92, 99, 1),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 34.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
            color: Color.fromRGBO(64, 72, 82, 1)
          )
        )
      ),
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => InitPage(),
        // "/": (context) => SearchFilterPage()
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And it exits the application. Don't know what the problem is, and how should I fix this. I have tried to google it, seems like couldn't find a better solution for this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Flutter Doctor results:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.8.1-pre.44, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: The error is quite clear. You are passing a `Utf8Decoder` instead of a `StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>`.

Comment: I have not written any code like this, it is not at all showing any problem file, just the package file. How should I fix it @10101010?

Comment: The error mentions the file `main.dart`. Is there no such code in that file?

Comment: No such code in that file. If you look closely into the path, it is showing the `geocoder's file path`, which I don't know how to access. Since in order to import the package, I just use, `geocoder ^0.1.2`

Comment: Ok I get it. It seems like the package your are using isn't compatible with the latest version of flutter.

Comment: Any way to fix it, cos my project depends on it @10101010

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196177/discussion-between-10101010-and-alok).

Answer (score 0):

change this line    final response = await request. close().
to
    final response = await request.close().then((response){ response.cast>().transform(utf8.decoder).listen((content) { return content; }); });

This worked for me 
Inside flutter plugins, geocoder and file name distant_google.dart

Comment: Is there any option to do the same in the flutter project. Cos what we can do is to import the package and we're done. We cannot make changes in the code of packages explicitly